# Name of plastic piece

Tags: windows, mounting, construction, interior, metal

Where can I buy this plastic piece?

[image]

Here is another pic:

[image]

I need it to place it between these two metal rods so that the curtain will slide easier:

[image]

Now I don't need this exact same piece but something like it will do. Maybe someone can tell me what it's called or maybe what to look for to buy something that can serve the same purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it back in & on, they are & I call them bushings. They just center the smaller rod within the bigger rod. It's not a locking collar & even if it were broken in 2 it would still function normally. You can sparingly glue it to the inside of the big rod if it keeps slipping out. Other than that, you should be able to find replacements at Home Improvement & Fabric or Window Treatment stores.

Comment: Happy to help! I hope it goes quick & easy & you never have to deal with it again.